# Is it possible to extract profile info of Linkedin group members?

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

Is it possible to extract profile info of Linkedin group members? Seems to me Linkedin API does not allow it, doesn't it? 
Some options:

1. I being a member of a group
2. I being **not** a member of a group.

If it is possible then what would be the way?

Comment: what sort of information are we talking about here? basic/public?

Comment: @NSNoob, yes, basic public frofile.

Comment: @NSNoob could you please give some suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849520/how-to-fetch-linkedin-user-data

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/groups-fields), the group fields do not include any fields regarding the personal details of group members. Also the [documentation](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#profiledetails) does not offer any way to get profiles of members. So I'd say it is not possible to get profile information of group members other than knowing their group-related traits.